# Bootstrap 3 grid system - not showing as grid - what file have I missed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following in my header...

```
<!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
<script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

...and the following on my page...

```
<div class="container">    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
</div>
```

...but the grid layout isn't appearing.  Instead it's just a vertically stacked column of text like so:

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

.col-md-1

Have I missed something in the head section?  I was expecting to see 12 columns.
Appreciate the help, thank you.
NJ

Comment: your code works. i would strongly suggest you missed some css or included an old version of bootastrap. Please include the relevant code in the head

Comment: Seems like I had an older version of bootstrap.min.css although I was following a Bootstrap 3 tutorial (www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNp5I_vO8IU). The grid system is now working but the new bootstrap.min.css has completely destroyed my navbar. I'll provide details below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the jQuery and Bootstrap Javascript in the page `<head>`

Comment: What should those references be? Checking the example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ it doesn't reference jQuery or Bootstrap JavaScript in the page?  Appreciate the help, thank you Khalid.

Comment: You know, you're right. Didn't know that you can use Bootstrap's grid system without the Javascript :) Check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `.col-md-1` to `.col-xs-1`

Comment: this would only change the behavior for devices with width between 768 and 992 px. his code is working if css is loaded correctly